# Comment was deleted but not understanding why

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments

Comments in my understanding should provide more details on the question, ask for more details, and overall build on the question.

My comment was just deleted and not understanding how it didnt fit.

The question was [regarding President Trump calling covid-19 the "china virus"](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/51121/why-is-trump-dubbing-covid-19-as-the-chinese-virus-considered-offensive-while). I posted a comment detailing his motives as he said they were as I felt it provided substance to the question. Yet it was deleted.

The question asked:

In any case, is the media backlash over Trump's nickname for COVID-19 justifiably warranted? Is there a problem in the way COVID-19 has been nicknamed?

I commented on what President Trump said his reasoning was firsthand. Yet answers that provide part oppinion* on his personality and reasoning are fine but a comment on his direct stated reasoning is not?

Part of answer that is more opinion based:
*"No doubt Trump does this intentionally. Trump thrives on the panicked, angry ignorance of others; that emotional state he knows how to manipulate to his own profit. And while he himself may not be concerned with the secondary impact of increased violence against people of Asian descent, people of Asian descent have a good deal to worry about"

Can someone explain why so I know what I can correct or how my contribution was not providing helpful information? I understand a huge part of a q&a site is people's bias but is stating direct information from the person in question a violation? Or did my direct statement from him not align with the question somehow? I dont quite see how but perhaps someone can help me understand.

Thanks!

Comment: Comments are temporary - they may get removed at any time for whatever reason. Please do not get overly attached to them. For more details, see the help article on the ["comment everywhere" privilege](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 3):

I believe that this was the comment you are referring to:

> To add a note as to why he is adamantly calling it the chinese virus. He stated it was a result of some officials in china at one point stating the us military may have caused the virus. He has adamantly called it the "chinese virus" at all chances as a result to combat a disinformation campaign. Whether is is the bare truth or not, this is one of the reasons he gave

Your comment was deleted because it was an attempt to answer the question. The purpose of comments is to discuss the question itself and how it could be improved by:

- Requesting clarification from the author;
- Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post
- Adding relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question).

Comments are **not** meant to answer the question. That's what **answers** are for.

For more information on how comments on questions should and should not be used, please check out [the help article on the commenting privilege](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). We moderators routinely remove comments which do not adhere to these guidelines.

Yes, I am aware that you are not able to answer this particular question yet, because it is [protected](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions). We routinely protect questions which became hot network questions and thus experience a lot of traffic from around the Stack Exchange network. The reason for that precaution is that we made bad experience in the past with new users posting answers on such questions. People often post answers on such questions which do not adhere to what the Politics.SE community usually expect from answers on this website, yet receive a large amount of upvotes because the users from other SE sites often have enough reputation to upvote answers (due to the association bonus) but not enough reputation to downvote. This incorrect feedback usually leads to a wrong impression for the answer author about how they should phrase answers on this website and subsequently leads to a bad experience if they post answers on further questions which receive less outside traffic.

If you want to start contributing to Politics Stack Exchange, then I would recommend you to start by answering a less frequented question or by asking a useful question yourself. The 10 reputation necessary for answering protected questions just require a single upvote on one of your questions or answers.

Comment: Interesting. I honestly didnt feel it was an answer and that it only provided a bit more background as one of his possible motives which is why I wrote it as a comment. So if I had written that as an answer it would have been deleted or marked down?

Comment: Provided a hit more relevant information*

Comment: Apologies, cant seem to type.  *wouldn't have been deleted or marked down

Comment: @Azfor Oh, you would have been downvoted, because that answer is positive about Trump. Sad, but true.